# Грамотность и школа

Tags: общие-вопросы

Когда я шел в первый класс, я практически не умел ни читать, ни писать. Но это не помешало мне стать пишущим журналистом и писателем. Сейчас же от детей уже при поступлении в школу требуют определенную технику чтения. Но при этой такой безграмотности на выходе, как сейчас, никогда раньше не было.
Как вы считаете, правильно ли то, что детей нужно учить писать и читать уже с пеленок, а в школу они должны идти полностью подготовленные по русскому языку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Повальная безграмотность - это беда всего нашего общества. И следствие неправильного воспитания детей в семье до 5 лет. Современные молодые родители гордятся и умиляются тем, что их чадо в 2-3 года сам включает мультики или пользуется мобильным телефоном. А то, что ребёнок не видит в доме книг, то, что продвинутые родители не читают ему сказку на ночь, - это, по мнению многих, не беда. Беда, и ещё какая.

Не нужно насильно учить ребёнка читать с пелёнок - нужно с пелёнок прививать любовь к книге и чтению. Родители должны сами каждый день демонстрировать эту любовь. Нужно воспитывать потребность в книге. Тогда даже и в 1 классе он быстро всему научится, чему следует учиться в школе. А если ребёнок сам захочет читать раньше - совсем хорошо!

Comment: Согласна!  
Мне в детстве очень много читали и, но сама я, признаться, до определенного возраста читать не любила. Любила слушать. Но потом без книги уже себя не представляла (помню, даже думала, что, если будет атомная война - тогда все ее боялись - то первым делом спасу из дома книги))).  
Но я все равно против раннего развития как самоцели. Ребенок — не бройлерный цыпленок, которого нужно кровь из носу вырастить за год)))

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом. Дети, которые начали читать до школы, лучше пишут. Они впитывают образ слова подсознательно.  А навязанные школе методики обучения письму и чтению  лет двадцать как уже только мешают, на мой взгляд, овладению грамотным письмом.

И я, и мои дети шли в школу, прочитав уже очень много сказок, сказочных повестей, рассказов. И если дочь хорошо воспринимала школьную теорию языка, то сын писал грамотно только вопреки ей, благодаря усвоенному образу слова до школы.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что оттого, что ребенка будут лишать детства, таская на бесконечные курсы "раннего развития" (зачем? Это что, бройлерный цыпленок?), они ни умнее, ни грамотнее не станут. Школа просто облегчила себе жизнь. Я не вижу, чтобы дети, рано научившиеся писать и читать, были грамотнее нас, которые читать и писать научились именно В ШКОЛЕ. Наоборот, то, что сейчас творится с грамотностью, это просто страшно.

Comment: Я не готовила своих детей специально ни в какой школе. Да и не было 25 лет назад такого. Все как-то само собой получалось. Мы читали - дети тоже. А сегодняшние родители многие книги в руки не берут, поэтому им легче заплатить деньги и ребёнка в субботу в школу отвести, а сам свободен.

Comment: Я слишком медленно готовила свой ответ... Вы уже всё сказали!Согласна на все 100.

Answer (score 0):

По мне так чем раньше - тем лучше. Если ребёнок "впитывает" навыки чтения без особых усилий со стороны обучающего, то пора. Сложнее, когда этого не происходит...

Но вообще-то это вопрос для специалистов. К сожалению то, что доводилось читать, отдаёт либо "кампанейщиной", либо, напротив, борьбой с ней. 
Чиновники и тут берут верх над педагогами.

Answer (score 0):

Не желательно ничего торопить. Мы сына, наоборот, **отучали** от излишнего интереса к буквам, цифрам, который начал проявляться с 2 - 2,5 лет. Это было как мания. Мы попрятали все игрушечные буквы, так он начал складывать их из палочек на улице. Так и научился писать печатными буквами (годам к 3,5 - 4). Хотя по другим параметрам у него было отставание. Говорить начал практически тогда же.

Знаете, что меня умилило? Примерно в этом возрасте он написал на асфальте мелом фразу, которая начиналась так: слово "о" ... И именно в кавычках! Уже было чутье.

Правда, теперь все равно не читает, книги "впихиваем" почти силой. Только "Маленький принц" хорошо пошел. Так что дело не только в родителях, к сожалению... (((

Comment: Читать и писать (печатными буквами) я начал ровно в три года, дочка - чуть позже. 
Никто ни меня, ни её специально не учил, просто "книжек не прятали". Насколько помню, мама просто рассказала мне про буквы, когда я окончательно надоел ей и бабушке-дедушке с требованиями почитать. все прошло в форме игры, какое насилие?

Comment: Меня читать тоже специально не учили, приставала с названиями букв - папа называл. Так и прочитала первое слово в 5 лет "Беломорканал" на папиросной пачке. Родители удивились, обрадовались и записали в библиотеку. Дочке читала вслух месяцев с девяти. Слушала внимательно! А когда я намеренно ошибалась, она громко возмущалась до тех пор, пока я ей правильно не прочту. И также настойчиво требовала почитать. Говорить поздно начала, а читать полюбила гораздо раньше!.

Comment: Кстати, по данным психологов, мозг нынешних детей развивается гораздо позже, чем лет 15-20, годам к 18. ЧТо причина, что следствие (мало читают - хуже мозг развивается, или медленнее мозг развивается, поэтому читать не хотят) - это вопрос к психологам.

Comment: Я, как и сын, научилась читать годам к 4, говорят, по вывескам. А вот брат начал учиться только в школе. И никто никакой трагедии из этого не делал. Потом он стал грамотным (во всех смыслах) специалистом и даже начальником.  

Хотя некоторое "культурное насилие" над ним все же сделали. Его, как и меня, отдали в английскую школу, что стало пыткой для родителей. Никак первое время язык у него не шел. Но зато к концу школы выправился, умел говорить.

Comment: Читать точно не знаю, во сколько научилась, явно до школы, но "Кот Василий, где ты был" тараторила в 2 года и 3 месяца через окно роддома маме с новорожденным братиком :) Чтение началось, видать, с ползания по папиным огромным газетам и требований "цитай!"

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что грамотность едва ли зависит от того, до школы или в школе научиться читать. Мне кажется, решающую роль играют задатки от природы. Грамотно писать, иметь языковое чутье - это как иметь музыкальный слух. Не каждому дано. Можно и не учить правила и относительно грамотно писать. С другой стороны, этому можно научиться. Как и хорошо водить машину, даже если ты не водитель от Бога. Но это сложнее. По моим наблюдениям, далеко не все люди, страстно любящие читать книги, грамотно пишут. Одни не могут пройти мимо, пока не запомнят, как пишется незнакомое слово, а другие просто не обращают на это внимания, хоть и читают очень много. Кстати о журналистах. Из опыта работы во многих изданиях могу сказать, что грамотных журналистов, к сожалению, подавляющее меньшинство (полагаю, автор вопроса как раз к нему относится, и не хочу обидеть журналистов, но имеем что имеем). У них, правда, другие приоритеты: важна скорость и некогда рыться в словарях, потому и существуют литредакторы и корректоры. Понимаю, все делают ошибки, даже профессионалы. Но иногда, простите, ТАКОГО начитаешься - глаза на лоб лезут.

Действительно сказки на ночь должны быть неотъемлемой частичкой детства. И большое упущение родителей, если с ребенком этого не проходили. Но вот требовать уметь читать до школы вряд ли хорошая идея. И так тяжело первоклашкам адаптироваться психологически к новому образу жизни. Получается, ответственность за обучение азбуке детей переложили с учителей на родителей. А если по каким-то причинам папа с мамой не смогли этого сделать (мало ли какие семьи бывают)? Не знаю... Учебные программы же не дураки составляют. Все же думаю, надо меньше требовать и больше заинтересовывать, мотивировать, как бы это сложно ни было. Только требовать - это просто. Но что хорошего от одного требования? Не знаешь - дурак, садись, двойка. И все, какой там интерес, одни слезы.

Comment: ДА где же это так - садись, двойка - за чтение в начальной школе? У первоклашек вообще никаких отметок нет!

Comment: К сожалению, в этом вопросе проявляются недостатки стандартизованной системы обучения. До школы каждый идет по своей траектории, в зависимости от способностей, родителей и т.п. А в школе всех надо учить по одинаковым программам. И что делать учителю? Один буквы учит, другой читает свободно. Заниматься первым - второй будет скучать. Заниматься вторым - первый не научится. Удобней, когда все примерно на одном уровне. Но не запретишь же учить читать дошкольников! Лучше подтягивать остальных. Тем более, что объем информации жутко вырос.

Comment: Я утрировала, конечно же. Когда у малыша что-то не получается, это огромный стресс.